# How do I put massege when my record was deleted?

Tags: php

"When i delete my record form database by php it will directly delete. How can i display alert massage for deleted data"

```
if (isset($_GET['isDeleted']) && $_GET['isDeleted'] == '1') {
    echo '
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="alert alert-success w-75" role="alert">
                The employee data has been removed.
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
}
```

Comment: Show us your code requesting delete a record.

Comment: $empno = $_GET['empno'];
$query = "DELETE FROM emp WHERE empno=" . $empno;
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
header("location: display.php?isDeleted=1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the alert message in the frontend, the best practice is to check with session.

For example:

In you controller (or where you deleted your database record), add alert message like this:

```
$_SESSION["alert"] = [
  'type' => 'deleted',
  'title' => 'Deleted',
  'message' => 'The employee data has been removed.',
];
```

- type is a css class name for style the alert.

Be sure you have started the session before:

```
session_start()
```

So, in the frontend (recommended in the header file), add a block like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['alert'])) {
  echo '
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center ' . $_SESSION['alert']['type'] . '">
        <h3>' . $_SESSION['alert']['title'] . '</h3>
        <div class="alert alert-success w-75" role="alert">
            ' . $_SESSION['alert']['message'] . '
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
     // remove the session, for display this alert just one time.
     unset($_SESSION['alert']);
}
```